# Snake Species Image Classification performing poorly

Tags: deep-learning, multiclass-classification, image-classification

I just started out with deep learning and I have a lot to learn yet. My first project is the following which tries to classify 5 different species of snake using a total of 17389 images for all the 5 classes(about 3500 per class). I have used a pretty small model; I am sure even a smaller would have worked fine. But my accuracy never goes above 30(max 50) & the loss is >1. I am totally new to this with just having knowledge about how different activations and layers work. I have tried tweaking the model but it does not make it improve.
Havent checked the data on test set cause the results are pretty bad.
I have done whatever basic preprocessing I know about.
Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
             rescale=1. / 255,
             data_format="channels_last",
             validation_split=0.25,)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                           train_data_dir,
                           target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                           batch_size=batch_size,
                           class_mode='categorical',
                           subset='training',
                           shuffle=True)

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                          validation_data_dir,
                          target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                          batch_size=batch_size,
                          class_mode='categorical',
                          subset='validation',
                          shuffle=True)

from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical 
train_labels = train_generator.classes
num_classes = len(train_generator.class_indices) 
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=num_classes)
print(train_labels)

# Creating a Sequential model
model= Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=(3,3), filters=32, activation='tanh', input_shape=(150,150,3,)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=30,kernel_size = (3,3),activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=30,kernel_size = (3,3),activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=30,kernel_size = (3,3),activation='tanh'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(20,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5,activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(
          loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
          metrics=['acc'],
          optimizer='adam'
         )

history = model.fit(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples//train_generator.batch_size,
epochs=epochs,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=validation_generator.samples//validation_generator.batch_size)
```

Can you please help me with where I am going wrong. I guess everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `class_mode='categorical'` your labels are one hot encoded, you don't need `train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=num_classes)` for second time. For detailed info you can refer [the docs](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/).

Also your 2DConv has a `tanh` activation, it is better to use `relu`

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters=30,kernel_size = (3,3),activation='relu'))
```

And try to increase your filters as you go deep in the NN, like this:

```
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size = (3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size = (3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256,kernel_size = (3,3),activation='relu'))
```

After flattening, use Dense layer which has more units:

```
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5,activation = 'softmax'))
```

You also don't need to set `steps_per_epoch` explicitly. `validation_generator.samples//validation_generator.batch_size` is equivalent to `len(validation_generator)` in this case.

Comment: The training accuracy is excessively high but the val_acc suffers. Is there any problem in the model or the preprocessing ? Tried reducing layers in the network to prevent overfitting; even the images are being shuffled. Also I tried printing out the labels of training data but it doesn't seem to one hot encode using class_mode='categorical'. Does it do it during the training because after calling flow_from_directory it doesn't seem to do so immediately

Comment: Try to use dropout or L2 regularization.